# Embedding UITableView embedded in a ScrollView, embedded in a UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, scrollview

I have a UIView that contains some controls etc...  This UIView also contains a scrollview that will house some content in a UITableView.

I have gotten everything working fine except I can't get the data from my fetchedResultsController to populate the table.

Does my main View need to be a UITableViewController?  Currently I have it as a UIViewController, since the UIView is the 'master' view.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is nothing more than a convenience class that implements the respective data source and delegate protocols on a normal `UIViewController`, so that won't matter. If you want some more concrete help, you'll have to post some code so people have an idea of what may be going on.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this answered my main question.  (I am new to these forums... how can I mark your comment as the answer?)

Comment: If mine is the answer you wish to mark as the answer, I will move it into an answer. If you would like anything expanded upon, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's request, my comment as an answer:

`UITableViewController` is nothing more than a convenience class that implements the respective data source and delegate protocols on a normal `UIViewController`, so that won't matter. If you want some more concrete help, you'll have to post some code so people have an idea of what may be going on.

Answer (score 1):

There are two protocols that your controller needs to adopt to make a `UITableView` work. One is the `UITableViewDelegate`, and one is the `UITableViewDataSource`. Make sure that you're hooking up both using `setDelegate` and `setDataSource`. In most simple examples, a single controller adopts both protocols.

Failing that, I suggest that you put breakpoints in your protocol implementation methods to ensure they're all getting fired. If not, there's a problem somewhere else, and we'd need to know more about your particular situation...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've got the delegates set up.  And I am hitting all of the tableview delegate methods... just stumped.  Anyway, I'll keep debugging.  Just thought I might also need to have the main controller be a UITableViewController, instead of a UIView controller.